# Cannot figure out how to align these columns of equations correctly

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I want to align these two columns of equations so that there is equal spacing between the numbers, operators, and equal signs throughout. Here is the code I'm using:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{alignat*}{7}
        54&\div2&{}=27 &&  \hspace{15em} && 283 &+ 638&{}=921\\
        200 &+ 692&{}=892 && \hspace{15em} && 1165&-221&=944\\
        330&\div22&{}=15 && \hspace{15em} && 504&\div24&=21\\
        1313&-761&{}=552 && \hspace{15em} && 126&\div18&=7\\
        217&-91&{}=126 && \hspace{15em}  && 1256&-584&=672\\
        462&\div22&{}=21 && \hspace{15em} && 17&\times6&=102\\
    \end{alignat*}
\end{center}
```

And heres my output:

[image]

Basically, I want it to look like the picture below, just with the equation completed.

[image]

I'm kind of stuck here and haven't been able to find a solution yet. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Why are you encasing the `alignat*` environment in a `center` environment?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
    54   & \div 2  && = 27  & \hspace{15em} 283  & + 638    && = 921 \\
    200  & + 692   && = 892 & \hspace{15em} 1165 & - 221    && = 944 \\
    330  & \div 22 && = 15  & \hspace{15em} 504  & \div 24  && = 21  \\
    1313 & - 761   && = 552 & \hspace{15em} 126  & \div 18  && = 7   \\
    217  & - 91    && = 126 & \hspace{15em} 1256 & - 584    && = 672 \\
    462  & \div 22 && = 21  & \hspace{15em} 17   & \times 6 && = 102 \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Just remember that in `align` and `alignat`, the first column is right-aligned, and then every time you switch columns with `&` the alignment switches between right- and left-alignment.

Answer (score 2):

By `alignat` (slightly modified @Vincent answer, +1) and with use of the `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
By alignat:
\begin{alignat*}{4}
    54   & \div 2  && = 27  & \hspace{15em} 283  & + 638    && = 921 \\
    200  & + 692   && = 892 &               1165 & - 221    && = 944 \\
    330  & \div 22 && = 15  &               504  & \div 24  && = 21  \\
    1313 & - 761   && = 552 &               126  & \div 18  && = 7   \\
    217  & - 91    && = 126 &               1256 & - 584    && = 672 \\
    462  & \div 22 && = 21  &               17   & \times 6 && = 102 \\
\end{alignat*}
Bay array:
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}
\begin{array}{rcll @{\hspace{15em}} rcll}
    54   & \div &   2 & = 27  &   283 & +      & 638 & = 921 \\
    200  & +    & 692 & = 892 &  1165 & -      & 221 & = 944 \\
    330  & \div &  22 & = 15  &   504 & \div   &  24 & = 21  \\
    1313 & -    & 761 & = 552 &   126 & \div   &  18 & = 7   \\
    217  & -    &  91 & = 126 &  1256 & -      & 584 & = 672 \\
    462  & \div &  22 & = 21  &    17 & \times &   6 & = 102 \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]